# How to use libraries with require.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, windows, requirejs

So I just recently found out that in order to use "require" to import a library from server-side, I need to use this callback function that makes stuff kind of complicated:

```
require([<link to request library>, <link to tmi.js library>], function(request,tmi)
{
    #code here
}
```

As opposed to the client side version:

```
request = require("request")
tmi = require("tmi.js")
```

I was just wondering if there's an easier way to use external libraries because with this way I have to find the links to the libraries themselves and I've been looking around for the tmi.js link without any luck. Not to mention that I have to put all the code for my program inside of this callback function in order for things to work. I just feel like there's something that I'm missing with the html that would make it easier.

Comment: Just use a bundler like Browserify or Webpack. Requirejs is not worth your time at this point. It's an obsolete practice.

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs I'll try those instead.